# railsでdependent: : destroyを設定したのに削除されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Parent, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Childをdestroyした時に
Parentのレコードだけ残ってしまいます。
何故でしょうか？

ChildはScaffoldで生成し、Parentはdeviseで使っているモデルです。

Rails 4.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dependent` optionは `has_many`につけるので

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
end
```

としてみてください。

あと`belongs_to :Parent` は動くのか確認していないのですが `belongs_to :parent` とするのが一般的です。誤解を恐れずに言えばシンボルは基本的に小文字でのみ使います。

Comment: `class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :parent, dependent: :destroy
    end`
小文字に変更するだけでうまくいきました。
大文字の場合だと特にエラーも出ないまま
オプションが効かないようなので地味に厄介ですね…。


モデル名が的確では無かったのですが、
今回は1:1の関係を持たせたったのと、
子の方を削除した場合に親も削除されるようにしたかったので
belongs_toを使っています。

Comment: 「Childを削除した時にParentを消す」とちゃんと書かれてましたね、すいません読み落としていました。解決したようでよかったです。

Answer (score -1):

:dependent => :destroy
書き方の問題ですかね？？？
試してみてください！！！

Comment: `dependent: :destroy`
は
`:dependent => :destroy`
の別の書き方なのですが、
古いバージョンのRubyだと対応していないかもしれないですね。ちなみに今回私が使用しているRubyのバージョンは2.3.0でしたが、無事に動きました。